# ASP.NET Core applications fail few hours after visual studio deployment to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I developed an ASP.NET Core web application. It works perfectly fine when tested locally. However, when I deploy the application on Azure, it deploys successfully, it works for a few minutes or hours (varying). I can access the database for logins and information. But after a while, any action that involves the database (login or retrieving data) does not work. Although the app is still online and working. What could be the problem? I have tried redeploying and the problem repeats itself.

Comment: The problem could be missing `close()` statements on the data base connections. I had this problem once using an mssql database. Make sure every opened connection is closed properly after the queries.

Comment: When you say stops working do you mean the site stops responding, to certain actions, or all requests, or you get errors immediately for every page? I assume Azure must have logs for you to look at to see what exceptions are being thrown?

Comment: @TomBombadil I am not using a separate mssql database. I am using the local DB from visual studio 2017

Comment: Still you need to close the connections. Is the error only occuring after some usage of your service or also when no calls are made?

Comment: @Rup have I editted the question to clarify what I mean by it stops responding

Comment: @TomBombadil How do I 'close the connections'?

Comment: Can you provide some of your code regarding the db calls? Normally there should be something like `Connection c = new ...;` and you can use `c.close()`.

Comment: The only connection statement I have is in the web.config file as part of the <connectionStrings>...</connectionstrings> and this is not a .cs file